# Quick-search files in Zend Studio 10's PHP Explorer

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt

I have recently switched from Eclipse PDT to Zend Studio 10, which is also Eclipse-based. One of the features Eclipse PDT had was that if you had the PHP explorer active (the left side area with the list of PHP files and folders) and started to type a filename on the keyboard, it automatically jumped to the file.

In Zend Studio 10 it seems to be working differently: if you start typing, only the first letter counts, so if I am looking for the word "dictionary" and start typing "dic", it does not jump to dictionary, it stops at the first entry starting with d (for example a folder named "default").

Is there a way to change this behavior so that it is like it was in older Eclipse+PDT?

Comment: which OS? (since it depends on OS, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408375)

Comment: @atlanto This is on OSX. I am, however, talking about the "PHP Explorer" view which never had a field for searching. You could instead just type away when the view was selected and it was jumping to the first file which started with the letters you typed in.